# VsCode intelliSense Problem with Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some problems with intelliSense with class Sequelize.Model
A lot of methods from Model doesn't linked with IS in vscode after set property Sequelize.Model

[With default class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xf1P.jpg)

[With @property jsdoc Sequelize.Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TioTo.jpg)

```
 /**
  * @typedef DB
  * 
  * @property {Sequelize} sequelize
  * @property {Sequelize.Model} User
  * @property {Sequelize.Model} Product
  */

/**
 * @type {DB}
 */
const db = {
    ...models,
    sequelize
};
db.User.
```

Comment: Just to be sure, did you actually load (require) Sequelize in the same file than your db?

Comment: @Booster2ooo yes, look at screenshots pls

Comment: I'm probably tired but I don't see any require() on the screenshots :(

Comment: @Booster2ooo you can understand that by links on first screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import also the typedef

for me this works pretty good!

```js
'use strict';
/**
* @typedef {import('sequelize').Sequelize} Sequelize
* @typedef {import('sequelize/types')} DataTypes
*/

/**
* @param {DataTypes} DataTypes
* @param {Sequelize} Sequelize
* @returns
*/
module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {



    const Post = Sequelize.define('Post', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        headline: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        body: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,

            defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()')
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,

            defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()')
        },
    }, { timestamps: true });
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Post.belongsTo(models.User);
    };
    return Post;
};
```